# AngularJS - Using a custom filter and ngClick to update same ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a simple `ng-repeat`. The `ng-reapeat` can be populated in 2 ways, firstly by typing a value and clicking the Submit button, secondly, entering values and the list automatically updates.

The issue i am finding is that when a user clicks on Sumbit, the `ng-repeat` that uses the filter does not update.

Heres a plunker (type Help): http://plnkr.co/edit/1qR6CucQdsGqYnVvk70A?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div id="fixed" directive-when-scrolled="loadMore()">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items | limitTo: limit | filter: search">{{ i.Title }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br>


<input ng-model="searchText">
<button ng-click="performSearch(searchText)">Submit</button>


<div>
  <strong>Result Search onClick</strong>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in filtered">
      <p>{{ item.Title }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {  

$scope.limit = 5;

  var counter = 0;
  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $scope.limit += 5;
  };

  $scope.loadMore();

  $scope.performSearch = function(searchText) {
        $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.items, $scope.search);
    }

    $scope.search = function (item){
        if (!$scope.searchText)
            return true;

        if (item.Title.indexOf($scope.searchText)!=-1 || item.Title.indexOf($scope.searchText)!=-1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
    };


});


app.directive("directiveWhenScrolled", function() {
  return function(scope, elm, attr) {
    var raw = elm[0];

    elm.bind('scroll', function() {
      if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
        scope.$apply(attr.directiveWhenScrolled);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Any ideas how i can use a single ng-repeat that bot updates on Click and whilst a user types in values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the model name you pass to filter

#### it's

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items | limitTo: limit | filter: search">{{ i.Title }}</li>
```

#### should be

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items | limitTo: limit | filter: searchText">{{ i.Title }}</li>
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle or plunker?